# How to get specific array value from associative array using single function argument in php

Tags: php

In this case I tried google so many times but I can't get my answer, so I'm posting here to get some solution.

I want to get a specific value from `$options` array using a function with argument.

I tried google so many times but I can't get my answer.

```
<?php

function get_option($option){
    $options = array(
        "server" => "localhost",
        "user" => "root",
        "pass" => "mypass",
        "db" => "myDB"
    );
    // any loop or something

    return $option;
} 

echo get_option('server');
?>

localhost
```

Answer (score 1):

As this is an associative array and you need to get values from the key, you can't just return the values using `return $option;`. You need to get the exact value by parsing the key to the array.

```
$options[$option];
```

`$options` is the array and `[$option]` is the key that you pass to the `get_option($option)` function. So when you call that function like this,

```
echo get_option('server');
```

The function will return the corresponding value according to the key provided by you. So the value for the array key `server` is `localhost`.

Try the following code,

```
<?php

function get_option($option) {
    $options = array(
        "server" => "localhost",
        "user" => "root",
        "pass" => "mypass",
        "db" => "myDB"
    );

    return $options[$option];
}

echo get_option('server');

?>
```